# Alternatives to returning 0 if value is null in postgreSQL/Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, amazon-redshift, coalesce

I currently have a query that is returning a zero if the value is null, and I am wanting to find alternative ways of writing this so that it works in PostgreSQL/redshift.

```
 coalesce(sum(Score)/nullif(sum(ScorePrem),0),0) as percent
```

Please provide me with alternatives which will help me get around the error of nested aggregates

Comment: This should work in Postgres and should work in Redshift as well.  What is the issue?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it currently gives me the following error: "nested aggregate calls are not allowed" Not sure if you have redshift and can try this yourself to produce the same error but I currently get it. The strange thing is sometimes it doesn't throw it if I have just my one select but if I have the union with the other select it throws it bad

Comment: . . That error doesn't seem related to this code.

Comment: I don't see a nested aggregate function in that line. Is that the whole query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff please see code above and let me know what you think

Comment: @Nick please see code above and let me know your thoughts on why I am getting this error

Comment: @an1234 . . . Simplify your code until you isolate the error.  Start by choosing one side of the `union all`.  Then remove columns, until you determine what is causing the problem.  And what is this line supposed to be:  `RPTBRANCH = 'Entire'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the strange thing is I think the union is causing it. If I comment out the UNION along with the last SELECT clause it is totally fine. If I bring it back in it starts outlining the query again and throwing errors

Comment: although Redshift and Postgres share some very ancient roots they are very different products. If you are not really using Postgres, then please don't add its tag to the question. The query will not generate that error message with Postgres (as shown in my comments on your previous identical question).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a `case` expression:

```
(case when sum(ScorePrem) = 0 then 0
      else sum(Score) / sum(ScorePrem)
 end)
```

However, your code should work.

EDIT:

You have at least one problem in the second query.  You are using `=` to assign an alias.  But in Redshift that is just a boolean expression -- and one not in the `GROUP BY`.  So:

```
SELECT calendar_month_id, day_of_month, month_name, DaysRemaining, 
       'Entire' as RPTBRANCH, 1 as TotalGrp,
       sum(Score) as score,
       SUM(ScorePrem) as ScorePrem,
       coalesce(sum(Score)/nullif(sum(ScorePrem),0),0) as percent
FROM  #temp_score
GROUP BY calendar_month_id, day_of_month, month_name, DaysRemaining
```

Comment: let me try this out and see. It does work if you run it in just PostgreSQL alone,however, I am using redshift to run the query and redshift doesn't like it so I am trying to find alternatives. Redshift runs PostgreSQL database

Comment: @an1234 . . . RedShift does not "run the Postgres database".  RedShift was developed from Postgres code as it existed about 10 years ago.

Comment: okay that is my mistake by saying that. I just noticed it kept telling me the PostgreSQL version which is why I thought it did.

Comment: fixed that as well and it is still giving me the error in redshift, you did make a good point though. Still not sure why it doesn't like the query

Comment: strange thing is that I took the aliases off of sum(score) and sum(scorePrem) and there are now no errors. Now I am curious to understand why it doesn't like aliases lol